# How to listen to a child view IBAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a superview which contains a childview.

In the childview, I have some buttons connecting to the actions in childview.

I want to make my superview also response to these button events, how can I do that?

```
SuperView.m

@property (strong, nonatomic) ChildView *childView;

//view did load
childView = [[ChildView alloc] init];


ChildView.m

- (IBAction)someButtonTouched:(id)sender {
    //Event Handling in ChildView
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, consider MVC rules (that u **don't** want to break), I suggest u to use `NSNotificationCenter.`

So, Simply `postNotification` when the button pressed in the childView:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"buttonPressedOnChildView" object:self userInfo:nil];
```

And in your `superView` u should `addObserver` like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doButtonPressedInChildView:)
                                             name:@"buttonPressedOnChildView"
                                           object:nil];
```

Don't forget to add method in the `superView`:

```
-(void)doButtonPressedInChildView:(NSNotification*)notification {
    // Do something in superView
}
```

Make sure u `removeObservers` in the `superView` `viewDidDisapear:`

```
-(void)viewWillDisppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Comment: Thank you @gran33, it's what I want.